# How do I find a certain node of a binary tree, using recursion?

Tags: java

How do I write the code to find a certain node. Specifically how do I say a node was visited after I check it?

```
public Iterator<T> pathToRoot(T targetElement, BinaryTreeNode<T> current)
        throws ElementNotFoundException
    {
        Stack<BinaryTreeNode<T>> myStack = new Stack<>();
        if (current == null)
            return null;

        if (current.element.equals(targetElement)) //found it
        {
            myStack.push(current); //adds the current element to the stack 
        }
            // mark as visited
            //mark node also as found
            // return the found element

        if (current.hasLeftChild() || current.hasRightChild()) //if the current node has a left or right child
        {
            // mark node as visited
        }
        if (current.hasLeftChild())//if the current node has a left child node
            pathToRoot(targetElement, current.getLeft()); // check the left child node

        if (current.hasRightChild())//same thing as above but for the right
            pathToRoot(targetElement, current.getRight());

        if(current != targetElement && /*node has been visited*/)
            myStack.pop(); // pop node from the stack

        return myStack.toString(); //return string of path to root
    }
```

/*using a dfs search to find a node*/

Comment: A tree cannot contain cycles, you don't need to check that you visited something.

Answer (score 1):

The sole purpose of marking a graph node as visited is to make sure you won't get into an infinite loop, because a graph can contain a cycle.

A binary tree is a special kind of a graph, that doesn't contain cycles, therefore there's no need to mark nodes as visited when you're doing traversal.

Also, usually binary trees are ordered in a way that the current node contains value X, its left sub-tree has nodes that have values less than X, and its right sub-tree has nodes that have values greater than X. This allows having searches that take logarithmic time, in your demonstrated code you don't seem to utilize that.

So, I think you don't have a good understanding of how binary trees work and you should research a little more, before implementing this functionality.

Comment: To be fair, if each node is not aware of it's parent, you would need to keep track of which nodes are visited. But once again, it's much more easier to fix the structure underneath than to solve it this way

Comment: @HarisNadeem since each node has only 1 direct parent, the tree structure you describe would be weird.